# Java Logger (java.util.logging)

Tags: java

Мой лог выводиться в таком виде:

> июл 06, 2019 2:46:04 AM Core.lexer lexer
>
> INFO: |The end of the analysis|
>
> июл 06, 2019 2:46:04 AM Core.lexer lexer
>
> INFO: |The end of the analysis|

Есть-ли способ, отформатировать в следующий вид:

> Дата: Сообщение

Нужно избавиться от переноса строки после даты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example.java**

```
public class Example {
    private static Logger LOGGER;

    static {
        try (InputStream stream = Example.class
                                         .getClassLoader()
                                         .getResourceAsStream("logging.properties")) {
            LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(stream);
            LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName());

        } catch (IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.info("Test");
    }
}
```

**logging.properties**

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=[%1$tF] %5$s %n
```

Comment: Все так, только этот код не скомпилируется... из за `final`, плюс заочно =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ и правда, исправил.

Comment: А это единственный способ как сконфигурировать логгер через конфиг? Я просто ради интереса спрашиваю, было бы логично иметь какой то метод из коробки, которому просто имя файла скормить и получить настроенный логгер.

Comment: @tym32167 можно при запуске JVM передать путь к файлу конфигурации в аргументе `java.util.logging.config.file`.

Comment: Точно, я об этом забыл, спасибо :)